# Feed Dialog posts to wall not showing on the news feed

Tags: facebook

I am using Feed Dialog `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/` and when a post is made it shows up on the target wall but not on the newsfeed.  Also if someone then browsing the wall posts a "Like" or comment it does not show up on any newsfeed nor on the wall of the poster.

Here is an example of the URL to post `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=417204058317545&link=http://www.kilcooleac.com&to=kilcooleac&picture=http://www.kilcooleac.com/images/fb3.jpg&name=Kilcoole%20AC&caption=Kilcoole%20ac& description=Fionnuala%20Britton%20running%2010k%20in%20the%20Olympics%20for%20Ireland%209:25pm%20Friday%203rd%20August&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/kilcooleac`

I have searched and found two similar posts on SO but without solutions.  Google search brings up a bug report that is similar `http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/405986669448307`

I have posted a bug on Facebook `https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/507380435954622`

All help/suggestions gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: In Facebook Developers > Your App > Configurations > Advanced > Canvas Settings > Social Discovery is enabled ?

Comment: Thank you João, I can not find such a setting for Social Discovery. I have posted the screen I see to [link](http://i.imgur.com/33hPt.jpg) @joao-mosmann. Would you like to try the URL code above to see what happens yourself? I would need to set you up as a friend first though [link](http://www.facebook.com/kilcooleac) many thanks again João.

Answer (score 1):

Posts won't immediately appear in the user's news feed, it will however appear in the timeline straight away. This is because Facebook have an algorithm that only shows certain content on the news feed. Try changing your Newsfeed settings to Most Recent and you might see the post appear. Most users have the default setting of Most Popular set.